# Как устранить ошибку?

Tags: android, gradle

пытаюсь запустить проект, и мне выдаёт такую ошибку, что делать?

```
The specified Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip' does not exist.
```

Comment: Попробуйте удалить этот Gradle и снова открыть студио

Comment: @ils2 Сейчас попробую

Comment: @nikita-game Ну как помогло?

Comment: @ils2 да, помогло спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте удалить этот Gradle и снова открыть студио